# How to list all text files in a directory

Tags: java, text-files

I tried to write the following code, but it does not work.

```
public File[] finder(String dirName) {
    File dir = new File(dirName);

    return dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
            return filename.endsWith(".txt");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: We can't guess the error. Tell us, then maybe we can help.

Comment: I usually don't use a FilenameFilter, but I check the extension myself and then I add each file to a list. But I think your usage is more correct

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921987/how-to-get-all-text-files-from-one-folder-using-java