# How to sort data from multiple files in java

Tags: java, file, sorting

I am currently playing around with java and I am wondering if it is possible to read from a few files, and then sort the contents from all of them (alphabetically)?

If that is possible would I be able to take an entire line, and sort it based on the first phrase?

Example:

This,

ECE3111    A-    4.00

ECE3031    A-    4.00

CS1003     B+    4.00

Would return this,

CS1003     B+    4.00

ECE 3031    A-    4.00

ECE3111 A-    4.00

The names will always have length 6 to 8 so is there a way of only sorting a line based on the first n number of places in the string?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: one suggestion is to sort the files separately and then do a merge...

Comment: Try something and come back with some code so we can help you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no attempt shown to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. In order to do this, you would need to follow this general flow:

- Create a `list` to store each line in
- Read first file (with a `BufferedReader`), storing line by line into the list
- Repeat above for each file
- Sort list of lines (can be done natively using `Java`'s `Collections` library with `Collections.sort(Collection<T> c)`
- Output each line from files, or process it as you need

First, create your list:

`List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();`

While we are reading the files, we will add each line to this `list` so we can store it, sort it, and output it later. Next, we need to read in each file and store it. A good guide on reading in files line by line in java can be found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/). I will do this with 1 file using a `BufferedReader` and the technique in the previous link. You can do this with multiple files by looping over the list of files that you need to read from.

```
    BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text.txt")); // Create reader with access to file
    String fileLine = fileReader.readLine(); // Read the first line
    while (fileLine != null) { // While there are still lines to read, keep reading
        lines.add(fileLine); // Store the current line
        fileLine = fileReader.readLine(); // Grab the next line
    }
    fileReader.close(); // Read all the lines, so close the read
```

The above code will read every line from the file `text.txt` and add it to the `list` that was created. Now we can use the `Java` `Collections` library, and sort the `list` of lines using that. This can be done by calling `Collections.sort(obj)`. So, with our code, we call:

```
Collections.sort(lines);
```

Now, inside of our `lines` list variable, we have a sorted `list` of all of the lines in the file(s) that we read. Now you can do whatever you need to with this sorted `list`! I decided to just output it.

```
    for(String line : lines){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

The full code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

    BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text.txt")); // Create reader with access to file
    String fileLine = fileReader.readLine(); // Read the first line
    while (fileLine != null) { // While there are still lines to read, keep reading
        lines.add(fileLine); // Store the current line
        fileLine = fileReader.readLine(); // Grab the next line
    }
    fileReader.close(); // Read all the lines, so close the read

    Collections.sort(lines);
    for(String line : lines){
        System.out.println(line);
    }

}
```

I ran this code on the file `text.txt` which contained:

```
ECE3111 A- 4.00
ECE3031 A- 4.00
CS1003 B+ 4.00
```

And I got the output:

```
CS1003 B+ 4.00
ECE3031 A- 4.00
ECE3111 A- 4.00
```

To get all files in a directory, we can create a `list` of `String` variables that represent a file's name. Then, loop over all files in a directory and check that they end with the extension that you are looking for.

```
    List<String> textFileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    File directory= new File("StackTxtFiles"); // Point to your directory you want to search
    for (File file : directory.listFiles()) // Loop over everything that exists in the directory
    {
       if (file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) // if the extension is ".txt", it's a text file so we should include it
       {
           textFileNames.add(file.getName()); // Add the file's name to the included list
       }
    }
```

Then, in your code for reading the files, put it inside of a loop looping over the `textFileNames` `list` and use the `String` variable as the file name passed into the `FileReader` rather than a hard-coded value.

```
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String fileName : textFileNames){ // Loop over each file that we found in the directory searching
        BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("StackTxtFiles/"+fileName)); // Create reader with access to file. Add the directory we are looking in
        String fileLine = fileReader.readLine(); // Read the first line
        while (fileLine != null) { // While there are still lines to read, keep reading
            lines.add(fileLine); // Store the current line
            fileLine = fileReader.readLine(); // Grab the next line
        }
        fileReader.close(); // Read all the lines, so close the read
    }
```

Comment: Currently I have something close to this, and I am trying to pass in a folder which has 3 different files that I want it to read through. Never done that before so do I just pass in the directory location instead of the filename?

Comment: You would need to loop through each file in a directly, and create a list of the names of the files you want to read. A good place where this is shown is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8922035/3753671 . While looping through the directory, add the txt files to a `list`. Once you have completed searching the directory, use the above file reading code, but put it inside of a `loop`. Then, pass the variables from the `list` (txt file names) into the `FileReader` instead of a hard coded name (mine was text.txt).

Comment: @Afatmunky I have updated my answer with some examples towards the end on how to search the directory. You can use this example code and apply it to your situation. I've commented the code in hopes that you can follow along and see what it is that I am accomplishing with it.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much. Got it working the way I want it to now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

I would recommend loading all the Strings into an `ArrayList<String>`, call `Collections.sort(<List name>);` and then use an enhanced `for` loop to write it out to the file of your choosing.

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TreeSet with a comparator of your choice.

So Set A could have a comparator that compares the entire words.

Set B could have a comparator that compares only the first 3 letters (substring) of the word.

Then you just iterate through the files, add them to your sets, and you're done.